# Validate substring in string with C

Tags: c, string, substring, string-matching

How to check if a given substring within a string in C?
The code below compares whether they are equal, but if there is one inside the other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main( )
{
   char str1[ ] = "test" ;
   char str2[ ] = "subtest" ;
   int i, j, k ;
   i = strcmp ( str1, "test" ) ;
   j = strcmp ( str1, str2 ) ;
   k = strcmp ( str1, "t" ) ;
   printf ( "\n%d %d %d", i, j, k ) ;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

Answer (score 3):

surely, as @paddy pointed

```
inline bool issubstr(const char *string, const char *substring )
{
    return( strstr(string, substring) ) ?  true: false ;
}
```

> ststr return a pointer to the beginning of the substring, or NULL if
>   the substring is not found.

more on strstr and friends [man page strstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

Comment: Just to add :  `strstr` returns a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of the entire sequence of characters specified in str2, or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in str1.

Comment: good option edited

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) 
function as mentioned by [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy)

```
 strstr() function returns the first occurance of the substring in a string.  If you are to find all occurances of a substring in a string than you have to use "String matching " algorithms such as,    
1)Naive String Matching
2)Rabin Karp   
3)Knuth Morris Pratt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use strstr

```
char str1[ ] = "subtest";
char str2[ ] = "test";
int index = -1;
char * found = strstr( str1, str2);

if (found != NULL)
{
  index = found - str1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strstr` in `<string.h>`

```
char* str = "This is a test";
char* sub = "is";
char* pos = strstr(str, sub);
if (pos != NULL)
    printf("Found the string '%s' in '%s'\n", sub, str);
```

Output:

```
Found the string 'is' in 'This is a test'
```